# Select by Category Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Been looking at the similar questions but still unsure:

Can I use the if statement to limit my sum by category name(s)?

```
<?php

$c = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post(); 

       if (get_the_category()=="Uncategorized") :
          $c++;           
       endif;
        
    endwhile;
     
    
endif;
echo "Count = $c";
        
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain your question in more details? What do you mean by `limit my sum`?

Comment: I'm trying to count the # of posts that are "Uncategorized."  Using the if statement to do that with $c++.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question right, you should be able to add something like this to your `if`

`if (get_the_category()=="Uncategorized" && $c < 5) :`

And whatever is inside the `if` statement would only execute for `$c < 5`

Comment: I"m trying to execute the if statement only if the current post's category is "Uncategorized"